# 'star' designations in Home folder explanation needed please

Tags: 20.04

New to Linux 20.04, and I mean nearly cluelessly new - Why would I want to 'star'a folder ( in my home folder) This is my first question to the Ubuntu community, Thank you for any insight, learning how to get around here,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The star feature is there to provide a means to have quick access to specific files you are working with at the moment. You currently need a file frequently, you star it, so next time, you find it in the Starred folder for quick access. Use it or do not use it as you prefer.

Comment: Thank you vanadium, I appreciate your response

Comment: @PointFermin You are welcome.

Comment: vanadium just realized I didn't vote for your answer, thanks again